# PC only boots with last known configuration

Tags: windows-xp, boot

I recently had to repair my Windows installation due to constant blue screens. Now the machine always goes to the Windows Advanced Start up options screen every time. Here, every option fails apart from the "last known good configuration".

Any idea what I can do to boot successfully every time?

Comment: Does it go back to "Last known Good" *every* time you reboot?

Comment: That's correct, it goes back to the menu everytime with "Last known Good" option.